# C# default parameters workaround

Tags: c#, default-parameters

Is there a workaround for default parameters? In C++ I would use

```
int foo(int k, bool check = false)
```

A tedious workaround would be to overload a function. An easier one? (There is no way just adding the variable and checking the calls of the function!!)

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C# (before 4.0) didn't support the default parameters. Even in c# 4.0 the default parameters are a bit different than in C++ - they're stored in metadata and, when you reference the assembly with default parameters, they're compiled into your code. So, if the default value was changed in the future, your code will still pass the OLD default value, which may cause the bad effect. So, use the overloaded functions with a single parameter and double parameters and call the one with more parameters passing the default value. Such approach will have a least side effect.

Comment: Cool approach Denis... Thanks ... C# is a little bit awkward from time to time ...

Comment: I didn't know that the default values get compiled into the consuming code. Thanks for mentioning that. I've added an answer with an example showing the effect. The [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) doesn't even mention this!

Answer (score 4):

In C#4, you can do the same. So this is allowed:

```
int foo(int k, bool check = false){
  ...
}
```

There are also possible to use named arguments in C#4 so you can call this method in many different ways:

```
foo(10, true);
foo(10);
foo(k: 10, check: true);
foo(check: true, k: 10);
```

named arguments are useful if you have several optional parameters, and only want to specify one of them that is not the first optional one, or to improve readability on the calling side.

Answer (score 4):

In C# 4.0 default and named parameters is supported now.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional parameters in your assemblies if they are build with MSBuild 4.0 (VS2010) even if you are targeting the .Net 2.0 framework.

The syntax is just like you said:

```
int foo(int k, bool check = false)
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry the project uses C# 2.0 :(

Comment: So does mine, I use VS2010 and the Compiler adds in the Optional params, not the Framework.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Denis Mazourick's answer about using <strike>default</strike> [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) in C# 4.0 and how the default values get compiled into the consuming class, try this.

Create a class library with the following code and build it:

```
public class ClassWithDefaultParameters {
    public string Msg { get; set; }

    public ClassWithDefaultParameters(string msg = "Hello World") {
        Msg = msg;
    }
}

public class ClassWithConstructorOverloads {
    public string Msg { get; set; }

    public ClassWithConstructorOverloads(string msg) {
        Msg = msg;
    }

    public ClassWithConstructorOverloads() : this("Hello World") {}
}
```

Now create a console application and reference the dll you just built (not the project, but the actual dll). Place this in your code and build the console application.

```
    static void Main() {
        var cwdp = new ClassWithDefaultParameters();
        var cwco = new ClassWithConstructorOverloads();

        Console.WriteLine(cwdp.Msg);
        Console.WriteLine(cwco.Msg);
   }
```

When you run the application, the output will be as you expected:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

Now open up the class library, and change both "Hello World" in "Hello Europe". Recompile the library and copy the dll to the output folder of the console application. Do **not** rebuild the console application.

When you run the console application again, the output will be:

```
Hello World
Hello Europe
```

Probably not what you expected! It's not until you rebuild the console application that both lines will print `Hello Europe`.

---

I didn't know this and I think I won't use the default parameters because of this. What's worse is that Microsoft doesn't mention this on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) page.

Answer (score 0):

well, there is no easier way, you could use `param` feature, but it is risky as well.

have a look at example for `string.Format()` where you can use it like:

```
stringA.Format("{0} is {1}", str1, str2)
```

that way you can pass any number of params, but it is quite tricky how u consume it and could be quite error prone